# "the reported by someone problem" vs "the problem that was reported by someone"

Tags: grammaticality

Could anyone please advise if the following sentence is grammatically correct.

> Sam addressed the reported by Tom problem.

Someone told me that it does not obey the English grammar and that it would be better to phrase it as

> Sam addressed the problem that was reported by Tom.

Comment: This is also possible: Sam addressed the problem reported by Tom. `the problem` is your direct object so you need to put it after your verb, and `repirted by Tom` gives more information about the problem so it should come after `the probleml`. `Reported by Tom` is called relative/adjective clause and cannot become before the word or phrase it explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sam addressed the problem that was reported by Tom.

is probably the meaning you intend. Tom reported a problem, and Sam is talking about it.

> Sam addressed the (reported by Tom) problem.

sounds convoluted, but could have some meaning.
If Tom reported many problems that were not really problems, and Sam was tired of hearing his complaints, then the problem is Tom. So Sam addressed the problem of too many annoying things reported by Tom. So:

> Sam addressed the (annoying things reported by Tom) problem.

But this is a stretch (trying really hard to make any sense) at best.